# Accessing Object in Powershell within CMD

Tags: powershell, email, cmd, outlook, pipe

I'm trying to extract the DisplayName from this object. On Powershell it's no problem, I just pipe and select DisplayName, and then I can .DisplayName afterwards to get only the email. The problem is I need to do this on CMD (long story) and I can't just type powershell on CMD and open up a powershell instance on my CMD; I need to be able to do it in one line. I've tried brackets and quotes of all varieties and can't figure it out. Is there a way for me to access DisplayName without piping and selecting? The object looks like

DisplayName : Email@somewhere.com

DeliveryStore : System.__ComObject

and a bunch more things like that. I thought it was a map (key:value), but .keys and other methods like that don't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Powershell]

[image: CMD]

Comment: Escape `|` with `^`: `^| Select ...`

Comment: Like this `powershell -c "(New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application').Session.Accounts | select DisplayName" ` worked fine for me in `cmd` so basically just by adding double-quotes.

Comment: Both of these solutions worked, thank you so much I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Mathias R. Jessen said to replace | with ^|

Santiago Squarzon said to surround it in double quotes

Both solutions worked for anyone else having the same issue.